# How to asign a tensor of value to another tensor of value by a tensor of indices (Pytorch)

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Given:

- a tensor A of zeroes has shape: (batch_size, vocab_size), lets say (16, 10000)
- a tensor B is tensor of indices has shape: (batch_size, seq_len), lets say (16, 20)
- a tensor C is tensor of value has shape: (batch_size, seq_len), -> (16, 20)

1. Now I want to replace values in A by C at indices B. Like: A[B] = C
2. I want to replace values in A by C at indices B except some indices. For example. B = [[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 4]] Replace the values of A by C at indices B except index 3 and 5 (apply for all rows) -> Now B can't expressed by a tensor because it doesn't have equal dim after filter. Something like this: A[B[valid_indices]] = C[valid_indices]

I tried use for loop but it cost 2 inner loop and take too long.

```
for i,row in enumerate(probs): 
            valid_indices = torch.tensor([idx[0] for idx in enumerate(encoder_input_ids[i]) if idx[1] not in [vocab['<pad>'],vocab['<unk>'], vocab['</s>']]])
            valid_ids = torch.tensor([idx[0] for idx in enumerate(encoder_input_ids[i]) if idx[1] not in [vocab['<pad>'],vocab['<unk>'], vocab['</s>']]])
            # print(valid_ids)
            # value = probs_c[i][valid_indices]
            # probs[i][tmp] = value #probs_c[i]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is my initial answer before you deleted and later edited [your post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78025970/1)**. It answer how to index `A` with `B` using values from `C` *under a condition* `M`.

---

You can achieve this by combining [`torch.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.scatter.html) and [`torch.where`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.where.html):

We start with a minimal setup:

```
>>> A = torch.rand(2,8)
>>> B = torch.randint(0, A.size(-1), size=(len(A), 5))
>>> C = torch.rand_like(B.float())
>>> M = torch.ones_like(A).bool()
```

Following your example *"except index 3 and 5 for all rows"*, we set both `M[:,3]` and `M[:,5] = False`. Then we can perform the indexing with `torch.scatter` (we can't `scatter_` directly on `A` because we do not know if a particular index is *valid* or not. So we instead do it out of place:

```
>>> O = torch.zeros_like(A).scatter_(dim=1, index=B, src=C)
```

Tensor `O` acts as a buffer *ie.* as if all rows were valid. The above line is equivalent to `O[j, B[b,j]] = C`, in pseudo-code. Then you can combine this with the initial tensor `A` based on the mask `M` using [`torch.where`](https://v):

```
>>> O.where(M, A) # equivalent to torch.where(M, O, A)
```

Comment: omg, I appreciate your help a lot

Answer (score 1):

With PyTorch using tensor indexing:

```
import torch

A = torch.tensor([[0.6301,  0.2310, -1.1964, -1.1293, -1.0428,  0.4011,  0.0519, -3.0591],
                  [1.3691, -0.7477, -0.9323, -0.3670, -0.1568, -0.1282, -0.4557,  0.1747]])

B = torch.tensor([[0, 2, 7, 7, 5],
                  [2, 4, 7, 2, 5]])

output = A[torch.arange(B.size(0)).unsqueeze(1), B]

print(output)
```